# React Native iOS - FlatList: click on any item in the list and show an alert

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-flatlist

I wanna know how can I make the action: touch in any item in the list (I'm using FlatList) and show an alert with the position clicked, in React Native - iOS. Follow below, the code must important of my DetailProduct class:

> **DetailProduct**

```
export default class DetailProduct extends React.Component {
  state = {
    stores: []
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({stores});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>

            <FlatList 
              data={this.state.stores}
              showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
              initialNumToRender={2}

              renderItem={({item, index}) => 

                <View style={styleItem.container}>
                  <View style={styleItem.holderImage}>
                    <Image source={{uri : item.logo_company}} style={{width: '100%', height: '100%'}} resizeMode='contain'/>
                  </View>
                  <Text style={item.amount > 0 ? styleItem.textAvailable : styleItem.textUnavailable}>{item.is_available == true ? 'Disponivel' : 'Indisponivel'}</Text>
                  <TouchableOpacity style={item.amount > 0 ? styleItem.qtdHolder : styleItem.qtdHolderUnavailable} activeOpacity={0.8}>        
                    <Text style={item.amount > 0 ? styleItem.textQtdNum : styleItem.textQtdNumUnavailable}>{item.amount}</Text>
                    <Image source={require('../imgs/assets/ic_arrow_detail_store.png')} style={item.amount > 0 ? styleItem.icShowDetail : {position: 'absolute', top: -1000}}/>
                  </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>

              }
              keyExtractor={item => item.id_store}
            />

      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to wrap your element (the one in your renderItem function) with a `TouchableWithoutFeedback` or `TouchableOpacity` element and add the `onPress` function to the Touchable element. In the `onPress` function then you can pass the item or index parameter that way you know which position is being clicked and also show the alert.